# Why does double clicking on the DataGrid Header not automaticly set the widht of the Column Content lenght?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have an DataGrid on which I used a style which looks like that:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF688CAF"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="VisibleWhenSelected"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="20" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer" Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}" Focusable="false" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>

                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="2" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and the other DataGrid Code:

```
                <DataGrid Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}"  Margin="10"  SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      SelectionMode="Single" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=collRMA, ElementName=vmRMA,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                      x:Name="datagrid" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
                      CanUserResizeRows="True" 
                      GridLinesVisibility="None"  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="380"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding artNumber}" Header="artNumber" Visibility="Hidden" Width="*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding position}" Header="Pos" Width="0.5*"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding description}" Header="description" Width="*"/>                     
                </DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Command="Copy"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <DataGrid.Resources>

                    
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Name="test" >
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10 0 0 0"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridColumnHeader_PreviewMouseDoubleClick"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="insideHeader" Background="Transparent">
                                        <Border x:Name="borderHeader" BorderThickness="0"
                                        CornerRadius="10" 
                                        Background="White"
                                        Padding="10,0,0,0"
                                        >
                                            <ContentPresenter />
                                        </Border>
                                        <!--<Thumb HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Name="PART_HeaderGripper"
                           Margin="0,4,0,4"
                           Width="2"/>-->
                                    </Grid>

                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="borderHeader" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource SecundaryGrayColor}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>

                    

                   
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>

                   
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="sans-serif"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333333"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                                    <Border x:Name="insideBorder" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0 2 0 1" BorderBrush="#dddddd">
                                        <Border x:Name="BorderCell" BorderThickness="0"
                                        CornerRadius="6"
                                        Background="White"
                                        Padding="8,5,0,5"
                                        Margin="2">
                                            <ContentPresenter/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter  Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.Resources>

            </DataGrid>
```

The Problem which I got now, is that when I double Click the Column Header, the Content of the Cell not widht the Content. So the widht doesnt  Fit the Content of the Cell if the Cells Content longer then the actual Cell widht. Anyone an Idea why the Cell Content dont update the Widht when I double click the Column Header?

Comment: what does your eventhandler do?
`<EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDoubleClick" Handler="DataGridColumnHeader_PreviewMouseDoubleClick"/>`

Comment: that was just a try from me, there is no code behind now